# Multi threading in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to spring batch.i have a requirement to read and process 500 000 lines from text to csv. My item processor is taking five min to process 100 lines which will result in almost 2 days for processing and writing 500k lines.

How to invoke the item reader and processor concurrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" for parallel processing and use it in your spring application context as follows:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
</bean>
```

And then you can specify this taskExecutor in some specific tasklet as follows:

```
<tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor">
    <chunk reader="deskReader" processor="deskProcessor"
           writer="deskWriter" commit-interval="1" />
</tasklet>
```

Note that you need to define the ItemReader, ItemWriter and ItemProcessor classes as specified here.
Also, the for parallel processing, you can specify the throttle-limit which specifies how many threads how want to run in parallel which is by default 4 if throttle-limit is not being specified.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped . Now my reader processor and writer are getting invoked in indefinite loop. Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: @Chris A step will run until your ItemReader returns null. In your case, your ItemReader never does, so it will never end. Please read the spring batch documentation also. Also you should accept the answer if it solved your issue.